# If GTR/LSS Operators in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have an increasingly large Batch file that uses `GTR`/`LSS` operators. The problem is that the `if` statements only permit me to enter certain values. In the following exemplar, typing in values of 2, 3 or 4 will return "Value too high."

```
:char_intb
set char_points=30
set /a limit=!char_points!-3
set /p char_int="How many points for intelligence? "
if "!char_int!" GTR "!limit!" echo Value too high. && goto char_intb
if "!char_int!" GTR "!char_points!" echo Insufficient points. && goto char_intb
if "!char_int!" LSS "1" echo Select a value greater than or equal to 1. && goto char_intb
set /a char_points=!char_points!-!char_int!
echo You now have !char_points! remaining.
```

There are others. As far as I've tested, it seems to only allow me to type 0 or 11.

```
set /p char_month="Month (0-11): "
if "!char_month!" GTR "11" echo Enter a value between 0 and 11. && echo. && goto last_char
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use double quotes `"!char_month!" GTR "11"` for **numeric compare**, in this case `cmd` will do a **string compare**. This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
:last_char
set /p "char_month=Month (0-11): "
if %char_month% GTR 11 (
    echo Enter a value between 0 and 11.
    echo.
    goto last_char
)
ECHO %char_month%
```

Comment: +1 And to add null checking add this line `if not defined char_month goto last_char` right after the `set /p` call.

Comment: I think it's better to do `if [%char_month%] GTR [11] (` because if %char_month% has no value the batch script would fail.