# Strange GTR error in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have written a batch file which allows me to setup custom ping request by entering the details, however when I attempt to run it I can enter the IP address without a problem and it will quit if I enter exit but when I enter a number for the packet size it will throw an unexpected error while evaluating `if %size% GTR 4096`.

I have looked at other posts here such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680639/if-gtr-lss-operators-in-batch) and as far as I can tell my code should work. What is wrong with it?

```
:pinger_presub_error
color 
echo Invalid input
set size = 64
pause > nul

:pinger
title Pinger
color 0B
cls
echo Enter exit at any point to quit.
echo.
echo Enter IP Adress to ping:
set /p IPAdress=
if "%IPAdress%" == "exit" goto end
echo.
echo Enter packet size 8-4096, leave empty for default(64):
set /p /a size=
if "%size%" == "exit" goto end
if "%size%" == "" set size = 64
if %size% GTR 4096 (goto pinger_presub_error)
if %size% LSS 8 (goto pinger_presub_error)
echo.
echo Enter number of echos 1-20, leave empty for default(1):
set /p /a echos=
if "%echos%" == "exit" goto end
if "%echos%" == "" set echo = 1
if %echos% GTR 20 (goto pinger_presub_error)
if %echos% LSS 1 (goto pinger_presub_error)
cls
echo [Ctrl]+[C] to end
ping /l %size% /t /n %echos% %IPAdress%
goto end

:end
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set /p /a size=
    ^..^...........one or the other.
```

Use `/p` to prompt the user and `/a` for arithmetics. Your code asks the user and the value retrieved is stored in a variable named `/a size`

```
          v .......space included in variable value
set size = 64
        ^ .........space included in variable name
```

Better use

```
set "size=64"
```

And, of course, change the indicated problems in the rest of the code. Your `echos` (that is also referenced as `echo`) variable has the same problems.

Answer (score 3):

```
set size = 64
```

sets a variable named `size<space>` to a value of `<space>64`

remove the spaces (or add a `/a`):

```
set "size=64"
```

or

```
set /a size = 64
```

Comment: +1, Interesting. I knew that SET /A would ignore spaces on the right side, but I had no idea it would strip spaces from the left side as well. Good to know.

Comment: @dbenham yes - confusing. I wished, it doesn't. This makes it hard to explain, why `set` (without `/a`) doesn't like the spaces.

Comment: Agreed. But the left/right symmetry is handy with expressions like the following: `set /a x *= ( y += 1 )`. I've used double assignments in one expression before (without the spaces) when optimizing a batch game for speed.

Comment: @dbenham ... there is a reason, why I remember you as the "Wizard of DOZ" :D